# Is there a difference between kernel PCA with a non-linear kernel vs PCA with a non-linear change of variables?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, kernel-trick

I see that [kernel PCA with a linear kernel is the same as PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101344/is-kernel-pca-with-linear-kernel-equivalent-to-standard-pca).

On Wikipedia's [introduction of the kernel to PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis#Introduction_of_the_Kernel_to_PCA) they suggest that there exists a non-trivial arbitrary choice of map $\Phi$ that is applied first to the feature space. From this a Gram matrix is constructed using the pairwise inner products of this map $\Phi$ applied to each feature, and then a familiar-looking exercise of [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is performed.

Do I understand correctly that kernel PCA with a non-linear kernel constructed with the choice of map $\Phi$ is equal to linear PCA with that choice of map $\Phi$ applied first to each of the features?

---

I suspect they are not entirely the same. For kernel PCA with a non-linear kernel the same map $\Phi$ is applied to each feature. But in transforming the features before PCA we can apply distinct non-linear transformations to each feature.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588327/is-there-a-multilinear-kernel-principal-components-analysis